# Install time verification of android Apps by ART vs DVM

Tags: android, dalvik, android-runtime

What kind of install time verification does DVM perform for an android App and what kind of tighter verification did ART introduce as compared to DVM.

Comment: Some (old) information about Dalvik's verifier can be found here: http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/verifier.html